# Blogger page title has never updated in google - Is it something in my blog code?

Tags: templates, blogs, blogger, page-title

My blogger page title has never updated in google? If i search zi photo blog it comes  up with a simple page title of zi photo blog | zi photography. I have updated this many times (to what the title actually is when you click through) and still it hasn't changed. Am i missing something really obvious? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Are you use Google web master? Also check your robots config in example.blogspot.com/robots.txt